# Performing a count of column from another column in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with two columns meetingID and caseID. The meetingIDs can be from one of three categories, so I use a subquery to select a particular one by returning only the meetingIDs from another table that match that category.

Once I have this list of meetingIDs I want to count how many of them have two caseIDs. I also need to exclude a few caseIDs from the count, but that's irrelevant for now.

Here's the code I have so far;

```
  SELECT COUNT( meetingID ) , meetingID
FROM case_meeting
WHERE meetingID
 IN (

SELECT DISTINCT a.meetingID
FROM case_meeting a
INNER JOIN meeting b ON a.meetingID = b.meetingID
WHERE b.categoryID =  '1'
)
GROUP BY meetingID
HAVING COUNT( caseID ) =2
```

The main problem I have is actually writing code that will successfully count the number of meetingIDs that have two caseIDs instead of returning a list of them.

at the moment the code is returning a list where the number of rows matches the figure i want and in each row is a '2'

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing ')' somewhere. Also, can you provide some sample data?

Comment: The `2` is the value of the `COUNT()` or `meetingID`? The query seems to be logically and syntactically correct.

Comment: yeh 2 is the count I want to make. how many meetingIDs have 2 caseIDs. This part is working. I just to need to count the rows from this query. I'm just not sure how to make a count of this query.

Comment: I can't do a sum of these rows because they are displaying 2 so it would give a figure of double what i want

Comment: Well, if your current query returns a list and all you want is to count the number of rows in the list, just put it inside another subquery and do a count(*).

Comment: For some reason I didn't manage it like that but it now works using this line of PHP $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(meetingID, caseID)`:

```
SELECT cm.meetingID
FROM case_meeting AS cm
  INNER JOIN meeting AS m 
    ON m.meetingID = cm.meetingID
WHERE m.categoryID = 1
GROUP BY cm.meetingID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 ;
```

If there isn't, change the last line to:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cm.caseID) = 2 ;
```